Where is the following verse about mantras found?
"Manasaiva yacchati, kamaye mahad artham,
Tasya vidyarthi bhavati, na cha vidyarthinaḥ."
"One who chants mantras with a pure mind, achieves great wealth and prosperity, but not one who chants without devotion."
Where is the verse found?
